# Macro command words in the index

Tags: macros, indexing

I use a bunch of terms that I need indexed but I'm haven't desided on if I'll keep the terms as they are. My idea was to simply use macros for these terms so that I would only need to make one chance if I deside otherwise.

The problem:

Lets take TermOne and TermTwo and use

```
\usepackage[totoc, initsep=0pt, columns=5, columnsep=10pt, hangindent=3pt, subindent=8pt, subsubindent=10pt]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\TermOne}{TermOne}
\newcommand{\TermTwo}{TermTwo}
```

Now I use the following for a "see also" index entry:

```
\newcommand{\gobblecomma}[1]{}
\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1} \index{#1!{}\string\gobblecomma@|seealso{#2}}}
\indexalso{\WordOne{}}{\WordTwo{}}
```

This produces the following in the idx file:

```
\indexentry{WordOne{}!{}\gobblecomma@|seealso{\WordTwo{}}}{PageNr}
```

This is a bit weird but the "{}" after the words goes away and it produces the result I want in the index in the pdf file.

The other commands I use are:

```
\index{\WordOne{}}
```

Doesn't seem to work at all and:

```
\index{Otherword!\WordOne{}}
```

It produces the folloing in the idx file:

```
\indexentry{OtherWord!\WordOne}{PageNr}
```

This will screw up the indexing as it starts with the "\". The same with the reverse order, or with 2 macros in \index. However; there also appears

```
\indexentry{WordOne}{PageNr}
```

But the page number corresponds with `\indexentry{OtherWord!\WordOne}{PageNr}` and not with `\index{\WordOne{}}` for some reason.

How can I fix this? It all works perfectly fine with regular entries but they just will not work with macos where the first example will.
I have tried

```
\newcommand{\indexsub}[2]{\index #1 ! #2}
```

And try to enter the macros that way in the hopes the text would get substitued before getting processed by the makeidx but LaTeX wouldn't fall for it. I have no idea why one will do what I want it to do and another will not.

Comment: I can't test as you didn't provide a full compilable non-MWE exhibiting documentclass/packages in use so that one could reproduce and track down the erroneous behavior using the same macro-definitions as you do. But I suppose the macro `\index` reads and tokenizes its argument under verbatim-catcode-régime or the like where only character-tokens but no command-tokens come into being. Your `\indexalso`-macro gathers arguments under normal catcode-régime and hereby command-tokens come into being as well.  Then it passes these tokens as arguments to the `\index`-macro and they can be carried out.

Comment: Do things work out if you do `\newcommand\myindex[1]{\index{#1}}` and use `\myindex` instead of `\index` ?  If so, then the problem was due to verbatim-catcode-issues circumvented by `\myindex` causing TeX to grab/read and tokenize the argument under normal catcode-régime and then pass it to `\index`.

Comment: About `\newcommand{\indexsub}[2]{\index #1 ! #2}` : Shouldn't the argument of `\index` be in curly braces?: `\newcommand{\indexsub}[2]{\index{#1!#2}}`

Comment: Correct, that was a typo.  I do use it with the brackets

Comment: The `\myindex` thing works..  but I still wonder why the same trick just won't work with the subentry command. It keeps using the slash as the first thing to index. I tried spacing the commands out or putting them together. As far as I can tell `\newcommand{\indexsub}[2]{\index{#1!#2}}` should work the exact same way but.. it doesn't.

Comment: E.g., with documentclass article the `\index`-command internally uses `\@wrindex` for writing index-entries to file. That in turn uses `\protected@write`. Which in turn implies that protected/robust control sequences are written unexpanded. (Control-words hereby are written with a trailing space.) Do you have protected/robust control-sequences within the arguments of `\indexsub`? If so, this might be the source of the problem. **I could probably do more than just blindly guess if you provided a minimal (non-)working example which I could use for reproducing the problem.**

Comment: I use documentclass[makeidx] book.
I found it makes a difference to use the brackets with the macro. Oddly enough that produces errors on making the index (the same nunber as macro entries) and I suspect that has to do with the brackets making it into the idx file but I can get it to produce the result I want in the pdf. So while it's not the way the systems likes it, the error handeling seems smart enough to figure out what I want. If I don't use the brackets at the end of the maco, it uses the word of the macro; but with slash in the idx. 
I guess the problem is solved. With errors.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your `\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1} \index{#1!{}\string\gobblecomma@|seealso{#2}}}`-thingie. Should this probably just be `\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1}\index{#1|seealso{#2}}}` ?

Comment: The purpose of that one is to get rid of the comma that appears before 'see' (it pretty much just eats the last character before 'see', which in the case of 'seealso' in de index is a comma). I thought the comma didn't look good and this is a solution I found stackexchange a while ago. It works fine and without errors (big cudos to the inventor). I didn't use it with macros for words I need indexed before. I'm probabably missing something dumb or some typos.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\newcommand{\indexalso}[2]{\index{#1} \index{#1@#1\string\gobblecomma|seealso{#2}}}` ?

Comment: Well, doing so removes the comma just as well but it then thinks that it's a different entry from a regular entry which creates a rather odd result: It makes a main entry with page number and the sub-entries below that; and a seperate main entry under that with the 'see also' attached to it without a page reference.